# Nautilus won't launch in Ubuntu 15.04. What should I do?

Tags: nautilus, kde, 15.04, plasma

Nautilus won't start. When I try to launch it from a terminal, I get the following messages:

```
(nautilus:3344): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed

(nautilus:3344): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed
Could not register the application: Timeout was reached

(nautilus:3344): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(nautilus:3344): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(nautilus:3344): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Could anyone suggest a way to fix this?

---

EDIT: Running `nautilus -c` produces the following output:

```
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
running nautilus_self_check_file_utilities
running nautilus_self_check_file_operations
running nautilus_self_check_directory
running nautilus_self_check_file
running nautilus_self_check_canvas_container
```

Comment: Did you try turning it off and on again?

Comment: try to run some tests using `nautilus -c` and list down the output

Comment: did you do something with nautilus-scripts?

Comment: @the_Seppi Yes, I've restarted.

Comment: @Maythux Thanks for the suggestion. I've added that output to the question above.

Comment: @d3pd do you have something with nautilus-scripts

Comment: @Maythux not that I am aware of

Comment: Same thing happening here

Answer (score 11):

After killing all nautilus proccesses, the problem is fixed for me:

```
$ killall nautilus
```

It is not a great soution either but it is easier than reboot :)

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem (today), with the same output with *nautilus -c*.
And as far as I know, nothing to do with nautilus-scripts.

Tried to logout, which seemed to be wrong solution. As I tried to login again, all I got was nice ubuntu background image and mouse cursor. No launcher, no top bar.

Then: 
**CTRL+ALT+F1** (at least this worked), did login and then *sudo reboot*.

After reboot & login everything seems to work normally (although I got some problems with NAS NFS mounts during shutdown and restart, but I think that's another problem - probably with systemd).

Somehow this reminds me of Windows and Explorer... maybe someone knows how to handle this without reboot (I wouldn't accept reboot as a solution).

Comment: Agreed on all counts. Reboot "worked" for me too, but is not a solution.